# Display only the projects of the logged-in user

Tags: django, django-filter, django-users

i'm working on a django project that manages some projects.
In a view I have to show only the projects of the logged in user, but everything i do doesn't work and i really don't know what else to try. I'm new to programming.

Basically my application has a Worker Model that has only a field: worker = models.ForeignKey(User)

Then it has a Responsable Model that has only one field: responsable = models.ForeignKey(User)
I have these 2 models because i need to separate the users in workers and responsables.

This is my project Model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
  client = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  urgent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  deadline = models.DateField()
  worker = models.ForeignKey(Worker, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  responsable = models.ForeignKey(Responsable, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is in my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Project

@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def projectsWorkers(request):
  user = request.user
  user_projects = Project.objects.filter(worker=user).order_by('deadline')
  template = 'projects/projects-worker-home.html'
  return render(request, template, {'user_projects': user_projects, 'user': user})
```

but i get an error:
Cannot query "Simone": Must be "Worker" instance.

I think that the problem is the fact that in my Project Model the worker field has a foreign key to Worker and not to User, but i can't change that, so what should i do?

Comment: How does the `Worder` model relates to the `User`? Can you share the `Worker` model? I assume it has a `ForeignKey`/`OneToOneField`/... to the user model?

Comment: Hi. This is my Worker Model: 

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Worker(models.Model):
    worker = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.worker}"

i really didn't understand what OnetoOne etc... things do, so i didn't use them.

Comment: please [edit] the question.

Comment: @Fede when your `Worker` has only one field, why don't you use `User` field as foreign key for `worker` attribute in your `Project` model

Comment: because otherwise in the admin panel i wouldn't know how to divide the users in workers and responsables. Because when someone adds a new Project, in the add form the person (that must be a responsable) has a select input where he can choose from the "list" of workers. So that he can associate the project to a worker. I don't know if i'm being clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment

> Basically my application has a Worker Model that has only a field: `worker = models.ForeignKey(User)`, you should access the `worker` field of the `Worker` model so:

```
user_projects = Project.objects.filter(worker__worker=user).order_by('deadline')
```

The first `worker` thus follows the `ForeignKey` from the `Project` model to the `Worker` model, and the second `worker` from the `Worker` model to the `User` model.